# Downsample cumulative timeseries by subtracting highest from lowest point in day

Tags: pandas, time-series

I have a meter reading in a dataframe that gives data in a cumulative reading (as in Xn+1=Xn+a where a is some arbitrary number.) Example below.

`2016-12-30 22:01:00  250785.399
2016-12-30 22:03:00  250785.804
2016-12-30 22:05:00  250786.207
2016-12-30 22:07:00  250786.581
2016-12-30 22:09:00  250787.034`

I have this kind of data for many months.

What is the fastest way to downsample this data with daily granularity, when each day would be the highest point for that day (last one) - the lowest point (first one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas has the resample method to change the frequency of data (can think of it like grouping data by a regular time interval). For what you want relatively straightforward:

```
data = pd.Series(
    [250785.399,
     250785.804,
     250786.207,
     250786.581,
     250787.034], 
    index=pd.to_datetime([
        '2016-12-30 22:01:00',
        '2016-12-30 22:03:00',
        '2016-12-30 22:05:00',
        '2016-12-30 22:07:00',
        '2016-12-30 22:09:00'
    ])
)  

end_of_day_values = data.resample("D").last()
start_of_day_values = data.resample("D").first()

daily_use = end_of_day_values - start_of_day_values
print(daily_use)
```

To get

```
2016-12-30    1.635
```

Answer (score 1):

You can using `groupby` and `transform`

```
df['Newval']=df.groupby(df.Date.str[:10]).Val.transform(lambda x : x.max()-x.min())
df
Out[405]: 
                  Date         Val  Newval
0  2016-12-30 22:01:00  250785.399   1.635
1  2016-12-30 22:03:00  250785.804   1.635
2  2016-12-30 22:05:00  250786.207   1.635
3  2016-12-30 22:07:00  250786.581   1.635
4  2016-12-30 22:09:00  250787.034   1.635
```